# bonding configuration when SLAVE=yes

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, bonding

In my network configuration I see the settings of `SLAVE=yes`

what is mean that - `SLAVE=yes`

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=none 
ONBOOT=yes 
# Settings for Bond 
MASTER=bond0 
SLAVE=yes
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1 
BOOTPROTO=none  
ONBOOT=yes 
USERCTL=no 
# Settings for bonding 
MASTER=bond0 
SLAVE=yes
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
DEVICE=eth2 
BOOTPROTO=none 
ONBOOT=yes 
MASTER=bond0 
SLAVE=yes
```

and in case both interfaces are slave , in the configuration seems to be as load balancing, then what is the procedure to test this configuration ?

I mean how to do real test on the bond that both ETH react as load balance ?

Comment: You're pretty far off target regarding understanding what's going on with this configuration. You should really read the kernel bonding documentation. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

Comment: I get the info from some site and it is  - This method of NIC teaming is called ‘Round-Robin‘, hence the ‘RR‘ in the name.This mode transmits packets in a sequential order from the first available slave through the last. If two real interfaces are slaves in the bond and two packets arrive destined out of the bonded interface the first will be transmitted on the first slave and the second frame will be transmitted on the second slave. The third packet will be sent on the first and so on. This provides load balancing and fault tolerance

Comment: can you post please your opinion an answer ?